# Immediately Restarting Play Framework's Development Server on Code Change (without First Requiring a Web Request)

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Is there a way to run Play's development server (started with run) such that it compiles *and* starts the server immediately upon a code change *without* having to receive a web request?

Various modes, by contrast, behave as follows:

1. `run` will compile and restart on web request after code change.
2. `~run` will compile immediately on code change and restart after web request.
3. `start` (now `testProd`) and `~start` will compile and start immediately (with undesirable API doc. overhead) with no restarts after code change.

An approximation of the behavior I'm wanting would be to run `watch -n 1 curl http://localhost:9000` in the background.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Good question, and I'm open to suggestions. I'm essentially using Play to quickly bootstrap an Akka application, but—without going into detail—it _will_ need to serve web requests from Play actions. Speaking more broadly, Play provides, out of the box, a number of useful faculties (chiefly [DI](http://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection), but there are others) to which I've become accustommed that would otherwise have to be cobbled together.

Comment: Try: https://github.com/jamesward/play-auto-refresh with chrome

Comment: Did you find any solution to it?